# change language option in ios App

Tags: ios

want to add a possibility to change language in application in my app, so when the current iPhone language is English. but user set turkish in app for my application I have to force my application to localize in turkish.

i am already add file  to setLanguage

LocalizationSystem.h
LocalizationSystem.m

on button Action i write given below code:

```
 if([sender tag]==0)
  {
    LocalizationSetLanguage(@"en");
    NSString * currentL = LocalizationGetLanguage;
    NSLog(@"currentL EN:%@",currentL);
   }
 else
  {
    LocalizationSetLanguage(@"tr");
    NSString * currentL = LocalizationGetLanguage;
    NSLog(@"currentL  TR:%@",currentL);
  }
```

this code doesn't change language.  In both NSLog it prints give below line:

```
   2014-09-11 15:54:30.640 uyarbeni[6480:70b] currentL EN:en
    2014-09-11 15:54:30.640 uyarbeni[6480:70b] currentL TR:en
```

when i look through the code in  LocalizationSystem.m file

```
  - (void) setLanguage:(NSString*) l
        {
        NSLog(@"preferredLang: %@", l);
        NSString *path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:l ofType:@"lproj" ];
          if (path == nil)
                [self resetLocalization];
          else
              bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] ;
        }
```

Please Help me to solve the problem.
But When i select language from device setting then language get change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set property in @"AppleLanguages" to have the selected language code by setting it via NSUserDefaults.

Like so:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:<your code>, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`

Comment: it working fine but language change after we stop execution and run again then only  language change ... i want to change at time of language selcetion

Comment: You will have to create your own functions to replace things such as NSLocalizedString which use this property to do it.

Comment: to view the changed language, i have to restart the app manually. Is there any solution to this problem so that i can see the change instantly.OR any way to restart app automatically after choosing language

Comment: You will have to create own functions to check current language as apple ones only detect language on launch

Comment: which type of function... my app have option to choose lang at that time i write code [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: That changes the language, but it won't take effect immediately, unless you make your own NSLocalizedStrings function.

Comment: how to make   NSLocalizedStrings function  what type of code i write. Now i am using NSLocalizedString(@"titleBarText", nil) to change text.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in my application, to change language use: `[NSBundle setLanguage:@"tr"];`

To use localized resources: `[[NSBundle localBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"plist"];`

Import header in ProjectName-Prefix.pch

```
//.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSBundle (Language)

+ (NSBundle *)localBundle;
+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language;

@end

//.m
#import "NSBundle + Language.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSString *currentLanguage;

static const char _bundle=0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle
@end

@implementation BundleEx
-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
    return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
}
@end

@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+ (NSBundle *)localBundle
{
    if (currentLanguage)
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentLanguage ofType:@"lproj"];
        return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    }
    else
    {
        return [NSBundle mainBundle];
    }
}

+(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
{
    currentLanguage = language;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```